# won't load new activity using intent? Meant to be once a button is pressed

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this is in my first class

```
    public void btnInput (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, inputTimetableEntry.class);
   startActivity(intent);
    }
```

inputTimetableEntry is the class that I want to link to.

Within that class I have

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
```

This is meant to go to the second class once clicked on a button with the id btnInput, any suggestions?

This is the XML used in the Main Activity:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.w15037204.w15037204assignment.timetableActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="STUDENT TIMETABLE"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:textColor="#ff6a00"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:id="@+id/listEntries"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Input Entry"
        android:id="@+id/btnInput"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff6a00"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So is `inputTimetableEntry` an `Activity`?

Comment: Post you activity layout xml please .

Comment: yes @Darwind it is the other activity I'm wishing to link to

Comment: @ShadabAnsari the XML has been posted

Comment: Add ‘android:onClick=btnInput‘ to your button in the XML.

Comment: @Darwind thank you! Sorry, I' m rather new to android!

Comment: No problem. You can also add the `OnClickListener` from code, by doing `Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {} });`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understood attaching the listeners to the views through xml correctly.
If you want to attach the listener to your views in the xml, the id of the views may be anything but it should have `onclick` attribute set for your view.
So your view should look like -

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Input Entry"
        android:id="@+id/btnInput" //Any id here
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff6a00"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="sayHello" //Name which you would be using in your Activity
        android:clickable="true" />
```

And define a method in your activity with the same name `sayHello` which accepts `View` reference as parameter

```
  public void sayHello(View view){
       //Code here
    }
```

Alternatively you can dynamically `setOnClickListener()` in your Activity without setting `onClick` attribute in your xml.

```
Button btnInput = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInput);
  btnInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Code here
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you! I've resolved this question now but this illustrates a good answer for others!